# Equality in Pandas DataFrames - Column Order Matters?

Tags: python, pandas

As part of a unit test, I need to test two DataFrames for equality.  The order of the columns in the DataFrames is not important to me.  However, it seems to matter to Pandas:

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(index = [1,2,3,4])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(index = [1,2,3,4])
df1['A'] = [1,2,3,4]
df1['B'] = [2,3,4,5]
df2['B'] = [2,3,4,5]
df2['A'] = [1,2,3,4]
df1 == df2
```

Results in:

```
Exception: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

I believe the expression `df1 == df2` should evaluate to a DataFrame containing all `True` values.  Obviously it's debatable what the correct functionality of `==` should be in this context.  My question is: Is there a Pandas method that does what I want?  That is, is there a way to do equality comparison that ignores column order?

Comment: you can force the columns to be the same using this: `df1 == df2.reindex(columns=df1.columns)`

Comment: @Zelazny7 actually that won't always do it, e.g. if df2 has additional columns to df1.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could sort the columns using [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1.sort_index(axis=1) == df2.sort_index(axis=1)
```

This will evaluate to a dataframe of all `True` values.

---

As @osa comments this fails for NaN's and isn't particularly robust either, in practise using something similar to @quant's answer is probably recommended (Note: we want a bool rather than raise if there's an issue):

```
def my_equal(df1, df2):
    from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
    try:
        assert_frame_equal(df1.sort_index(axis=1), df2.sort_index(axis=1), check_names=True)
        return True
    except (AssertionError, ValueError, TypeError):  perhaps something else?
        return False
```

Comment: No, it does not work for missing values. Then you start doing `dropna` or `fillna` on various columns that are not matching. Then you realize that it dropped something else that you did not compare for equality, so you do `fillna` with some random values, different for different columns... and the whole thing becomes a mess.

Comment: @osa you're right you want to be using assert_frame_equal afterwards (I don't think pandas exports a similar), although beware of using it from quant's answer as that can raise (rather than return bool).

Comment: @osa I think you want to do something similar to quants but return a bool, have included a recipe.

Answer (score 46):

The most common intent is handled like this:

```
def assertFrameEqual(df1, df2, **kwds ):
    """ Assert that two dataframes are equal, ignoring ordering of columns"""
    from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
    return assert_frame_equal(df1.sort_index(axis=1), df2.sort_index(axis=1), check_names=True, **kwds )
```

Of course see `pandas.util.testing.assert_frame_equal` for other parameters you can pass

Comment: Don't sort. Pass `check_like` parameter. See other answers.

Answer (score 9):

`assert_frame_equal` from `pandas.testing` is a function which checks frames equality.
as mentioned in `assert_frame_equal` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html), if set `check_like` parameter to `True`, it will ignore order of index and columns.

Answer (score 6):

Usually you're going to want speedy tests and the sorting method can be brutally inefficient for larger indices (like if you were using rows instead of columns for this problem). The sort method is also susceptible to false negatives on non-unique indices.

Fortunately, `pandas.util.testing.assert_frame_equal` has since been updated with a `check_like` option. Set this to true and the ordering will not be considered in the test.

With non-unique indices, you'll get the cryptic `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. This is raised by the under-the-hood `reindex_like` operation that rearranges one of the DataFrames to match the other's order. Reindexing is *much* faster than sorting as evidenced below.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

df  = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1e6))
df1 = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42)
df2 = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=43)

%timeit -n 1 -r 5 assert_frame_equal(df1.sort_index(), df2.sort_index())
## 5.73 s ± 329 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit -n 1 -r 5 assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_like=True)
## 1.04 s ± 237 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For those who enjoy a good performance comparison plot:

[Reindexing vs sorting on int and str indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSWqr.png) (str even more drastic)

Answer (score 4):

```
def equal( df1, df2 ):
    """ Check if two DataFrames are equal, ignoring nans """
    return df1.fillna(1).sort_index(axis=1).eq(df2.fillna(1).sort_index(axis=1)).all().all()
```

Comment: `fillna(1)` is not very reliable, as people may have `1`s in the dataframe. At the very least, consider using `fillna(28347893)` instead, or better yet, `pandas.util.testing.assert_frame_equal` suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting column only works if the row and column labels match across the frames. Say, you have 2 dataframes with identical values in cells but with different labels,then the sort solution will not work. I ran into this scenario when implementing k-modes clustering using pandas.

I got around it with a simple equals function to check cell equality(code below)

```
def frames_equal(df1,df2) :
    if not isinstance(df1,DataFrame) or not isinstance(df2,DataFrame) :
        raise Exception(
            "dataframes should be an instance of pandas.DataFrame")

    if df1.shape != df2.shape:
        return False

    num_rows,num_cols = df1.shape
    for i in range(num_rows):
       match = sum(df1.iloc[i] == df2.iloc[i])
       if match != num_cols :
          return False
   return True
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using df1.equals(df2)? i think it's more reliable that df1==df2, though i'm not sure if it will resolve your issues with column order.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html

Comment: Does .equals require the sort order to be the same?

Comment: If you want to compare 2 Data Frames. Check-out flexible comparison in Pandas, using the methods like .eq(), .nq(), gt() and more... --> equal, not equal and greater then.

Example: 

`df['new_col'] = df.gt(df_1)`

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#flexible-comparisons

Comment: @danger89, `.eq` or `==` also seems to work only for sorted `DataFrames`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you may need function to compare DataFrames ignoring both row and column order? Only requirement is to have some unique column to use it as index.

```
f1 = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 1, "foo": "1", "bar": None},
    {"id": 2, "foo": "2", "bar": 2},
    {"id": 3, "foo": "3", "bar": 3},
    {"id": 4, "foo": "4", "bar": 4}
])
f2 = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 3, "foo": "3", "bar": 3},
    {"id": 1, "bar": None, "foo": "1",},
    {"id": 2, "foo": "2", "bar": 2},
    {"id": 4, "foo": "4", "bar": 4}
])

def comparable(df, index_col='id'):
    return df.fillna(value=0).set_index(index_col).to_dict('index')

comparable(f1) == comparable (f2)  # returns True
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do it is
(Assuming df1 and df2)

Check df1 and df2 columns are the same using a set (as order doesn't matter in a set)

```
columns_check = set(df1.columns) == set(df2.columns)
```

If they are different then the dataframe must be different.
If they are the same then you can use the columns of df2 to reorder the columns of df1

```
contents_check = df1[df2.columns].equals(df2)
```

The easiest would be:

```
if set(df1.columns) == set(df2.columns):
    equality_check = df1[df2.columns].equals(df2)
else: 
    equality_check = False
```

or you could even:

```
equality_check = False
if set(df1.columns) == set(df2.columns):
    equality_check = df1[df2.columns].equals(df2)
```

If you don't like that `else` chilling

but you can split out the columns check, into it's own variable (`columns_check` ) if you think it improves readability

If you try `df1[df2.columns].equals(df2)` without first checking the columns you could get an error (if `df2` has columns that `df1` doesn't) or something untrue (if `df1` has columns that `df2` doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

When working with dataframes containing python objects such as tuples and lists `df.eq(df2)` and `df == df2` will not suffice. Even if a the same cells in each dataframes contain the same object, such as `(0, 0)`, the equality comparison will result to `False`. To get around this, convert all columns to strings before comparison:

`df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str)).eq(df2.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str)))`