# Pandas "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects" error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas to compare the outputs of two files loaded into two data frames (uat, prod):
...

```
uat = uat[['Customer Number','Product']]
prod = prod[['Customer Number','Product']]
print uat['Customer Number'] == prod['Customer Number']
print uat['Product'] == prod['Product']
print uat == prod

The first two match exactly:
74357    True
74356    True
Name: Customer Number, dtype: bool
74357    True
74356    True
Name: Product, dtype: bool
```

For the third print, I get an error:
Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects. If the first two compared fine, what's wrong with the 3rd?

Thanks

Comment: had this problem after using `pd.concat`, answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528119/pandas-recalculate-index-after-a-concatenation) helped

Comment: Had this problem, for me kind of this worked, say you wanted to compare `id` values  :

`(df_1.sort_values('id').id.values == df_2.sort_values('id').id.values).all()`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Here's a small example to demonstrate this (which only applied to DataFrames, not Series, until Pandas 0.19 where it applies to both):

```
In [1]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [2]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4], [1, 2]], index=[1, 0])

In [3]: df1 == df2
Exception: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

One solution is to [sort the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) first (Note: [some functions require sorted indexes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-need-for-sortedness)):

```
In [4]: df2.sort_index(inplace=True)

In [5]: df1 == df2
Out[5]: 
      0     1
0  True  True
1  True  True
```

Note: `==` is also [sensitive to the order of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224172/equality-in-pandas-dataframes-column-order-matters), so you may have to use `sort_index(axis=1)`:

```
In [11]: df1.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1) == df2.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)
Out[11]: 
      0     1
0  True  True
1  True  True
```

Note: This can still raise (if the index/columns aren't identically labelled after sorting).

Comment: this will not work if order is important.

Answer (score 57):

You can also try dropping the index column if it is not needed to compare:

```
print(df1.reset_index(drop=True) == df2.reset_index(drop=True))
```

I have used this same technique in a unit test like so:

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

assert_frame_equal(actual.reset_index(drop=True), expected.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: You could consider adding `inplace=True` to ensure that the index is rest for downstream comparisons.

Answer (score 18):

At the time when this question was asked there wasn't another function in Pandas to test equality, but it has been added a while ago: [`pandas.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html)

You use it like this:

```py
df1.equals(df2)
```

Some differenes to `==` are:

- You don't get the error described in the question
- It returns a simple boolean.
- NaN values in the same location are considered equal
- 2 DataFrames need to have the same `dtype` to be considered equal, see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212697/confirming-equality-of-two-pandas-dataframes)

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in [@paperskilltrees answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error/70922824#70922824) index alignment is important. Apart from the solution provided there another option is to [sort the index of the DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) before comparing the DataFrames. For `df1` that would be `df1.sort_index(inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 11):

When you compare two DataFrames, you must ensure that the number of records in the first DataFrame matches with the number of records in the second DataFrame. In our example, each of the two DataFrames had 4 records, with 4 products and 4 prices.

If, for example, one of the DataFrames had 5 products, while the other DataFrame had 4 products, and you tried to run the comparison, you would get the following error:

**ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects**

this should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

firstProductSet = {'Product1': ['Computer','Phone','Printer','Desk'],
                   'Price1': [1200,800,200,350]
                   }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(firstProductSet,columns= ['Product1', 'Price1'])


secondProductSet = {'Product2': ['Computer','Phone','Printer','Desk'],
                    'Price2': [900,800,300,350]
                    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(secondProductSet,columns= ['Product2', 'Price2'])


df1['Price2'] = df2['Price2'] #add the Price2 column from df2 to df1

df1['pricesMatch?'] = np.where(df1['Price1'] == df2['Price2'], 'True', 'False')  #create new column in df1 to check if prices match
df1['priceDiff?'] = np.where(df1['Price1'] == df2['Price2'], 0, df1['Price1'] - df2['Price2']) #create new column in df1 for price diff 
print (df1)
```

example from https://datatofish.com/compare-values-dataframes/

Answer (score 7):

[Flyingdutchman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64385690/) is *great* but *wrong*: it uses [`DataFrame.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html), which will return `False` in your case.
Instead, you want to use [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), which will return `True`.

It seems that `DataFrame.equals` ignores the dataframe's index, while `DataFrame.eq` uses dataframes' indexes for alignment and then compares the aligned values. This is an occasion to [quote](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html) the central gotcha of Pandas:

> Here is a basic tenet to keep in mind: data alignment is intrinsic. The link between labels and data will not be broken unless done so explicitly by you.

As we can see in the following examples, the data alignment is neither broken, nor enforced, unless explicitly requested. So we have three different situations.

1. No explicit instruction given, as to the alignment: `==` aka `DataFrame.__eq__`,

```py
   In [1]: import pandas as pd
   In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], data={'col1':list('abc')})
   In [3]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=[2, 0, 1], data={'col1':list('cab')})
   In [4]: df1 == df2
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ...
   ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

2. Alignment is explicitly broken: `DataFrame.equals`, `DataFrame.values`, `DataFrame.reset_index()`,

```py
    In [5]: df1.equals(df2)
    Out[5]: False

    In [9]: df1.values == df2.values
    Out[9]: 
    array([[False],
           [False],
           [False]])

    In [10]: (df1.values == df2.values).all().all()
    Out[10]: False
```

3. Alignment is explicitly enforced: `DataFrame.eq`, `DataFrame.sort_index()`,

```py
    In [6]: df1.eq(df2)
    Out[6]: 
       col1
    0  True
    1  True
    2  True

    In [8]: df1.eq(df2).all().all()
    Out[8]: True
```

My answer is as of pandas version `1.0.3`.

**P.S.** When you compare a dataframe to itself, it is automatically aligned, so we may forget about alignment. Does this mean that all the above ways give you `True`? Only for a dataframe *without* missing values. But if a dataframe *contains missing values*, then `equals()` yields `True`, and all other ways yield `False`. This is because `equals()` treats two `NaN`s as equal, which is very unusual (by convention, `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`).

Answer (score 0):

Here I am showing a complete example of how to handle this error. I have added rows with zeros. You can have your dataframes from csv or any other source.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# df1 with 9 rows
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Mike','Smith','Wale','Marry','Tom','Menda','Bolt','Yuswa',],
    'Age':[23,45,12,34,27,44,28,39,40]})

# df2 with 8 rows
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Mike','Wale','Marry','Tom','Menda','Bolt','Yuswa',],
    'Age':[25,45,14,34,26,44,29,42]})


# get lengths of df1 and df2
df1_len = len(df1)
df2_len = len(df2)


diff = df1_len - df2_len

rows_to_be_added1 = rows_to_be_added2 = 0
# rows_to_be_added1 = np.zeros(diff)

if diff < 0:
    rows_to_be_added1 = abs(diff)
else:
    rows_to_be_added2 = diff
    
# add empty rows to df1
if rows_to_be_added1 > 0:
    df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((rows_to_be_added1,len(df1.columns))),columns=df1.columns))

# add empty rows to df2
if rows_to_be_added2 > 0:
    df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((rows_to_be_added2,len(df2.columns))),columns=df2.columns))

# at this point we have two dataframes with the same number of rows, and maybe different indexes
# drop the indexes of both, so we can compare the dataframes and other operations like update etc.
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# add a new column to df1
df1['New_age'] = None

# compare the Age column of df1 and df2, and update the New_age column of df1 with the Age column of df2 if they match, else None
df1['New_age'] = np.where(df1['Age'] == df2['Age'], df2['Age'], None)

# drop rows where Name is 0.0
df2 = df2.drop(df2[df2['Name'] == 0.0].index)

# now we don't get the error ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when **trying to sort a list of dataframes**.

I was trying to concatinate some dataframes together after sorting them in a list based on their index.

For example, I had:

- a dataframe for 2022 data, with an index which ran from 2022-01-01 to 2022-12-31
- a dataframe for 2023 data, with an index which ran from 2023-01-01 to 2023-12-31
- the dataframes have a single index, which is a datetime object

In this case, what I needed to do was add a `key` lambda function to `sorted` like this:

```
df_list_sorted = sorted(df_list, key=lambda df: df.iloc[0].name)
```

The key point here being this: **provide some way of specifying how the dataframes should be sorted**. This should be doing using the `key` parameter to the `sorted` function, where you can provide (for example) a lambda function to extract the key to sort by.

This works in this example because the dataframes contain ordered, and non-overlapping, indexes.

You could also achieve the same result by:

- concatinating the dataframes
- doing an inplace sort on the index

This will work for more complex cases where dataframes may overlap in their index, or where the index may not be sorted.

However, it will of course be slower, because an additional inplace sort is needed after the dataframes are concatinated.

Answer (score -1):

I found where the error is coming from in my case:

The problem was that column names list was accidentally enclosed in another list.

Consider following example:

```
column_names=['warrior','eat','ok','monkeys']

df_good = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(shape=(6,4)),columns=column_names)
df_good['ok'] < df_good['monkeys']

>>> 0    False
    1    False
    2    False
    3    False
    4    False
    5    False

df_bad = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(shape=(6,4)),columns=[column_names])
df_bad ['ok'] < df_bad ['monkeys']

>>> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

And the thing is you cannot visually distinguish the bad DataFrame from good.

Answer (score -1):

In my case i just write directly param **columns** in creating dataframe, because data from one sql-query was with names, and without in other