# Pandas recalculate index after a concatenation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem where I produce a pandas dataframe by concatenating along the row axis (stacking vertically).

Each of the constituent dataframes has an autogenerated index (ascending numbers).

After concatenation, my index is screwed up: it counts up to n (where n is the shape[0] of the corresponding dataframe), and restarts at zero at the next dataframe.

I am trying to "re-calculate the index, given the current order", or "re-index" (or so I thought).  Turns out that isn't exactly what `DataFrame.reindex` seems to be doing.

---

Here is what I tried to do:

```
train_df = pd.concat(train_class_df_list)
train_df = train_df.reindex(index=[i for i in range(train_df.shape[0])])
```

It failed with "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis." I don't want to change the order of my data... just need to delete the old index and set up a new one, with the order of rows preserved.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

After vertical concatenation, if you get an index of *[0, n)* followed by *[0, m)*, all you need to do is call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

(you can do this in place using `inplace=True`).

---

```
import pandas as pd

>>> pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]}), 
    pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})]).reset_index(drop=True)
    a
0   1
1   2
2   1
3   2
```

Answer (score 138):

If your index is autogenerated and you don't want to keep it, you can use the `ignore_index` option.
`

```
train_df = pd.concat(train_class_df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

This will autogenerate a new index for you, and my guess is that this is exactly what you are after.

Comment: This is more direct than `.reset_index(drop=True)` and thus IMO preferable, but the naming is somewhat less clear

Comment: Works better! Thanks!

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't work for me. It runs without creating an error, but for each concatenated file the indexing starts from 0

Comment: works for me great. And I agree with Dmitri's comment that ignore_index = True option is  more intuitive to explain others

Comment: This option will remove also the column names, so it's up to you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/43406062/7654451

Answer (score 11):

This should work:

```
train_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Set [drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to `True` to avoid an additional column in your dataframe.