# Pandas how to concat two dataframes without losing the column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following toy code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame()
 df["foo"] = [1,2,3,4]

 df2 = pd.DataFrame()
 df2["bar"]=[4,5,6,7]  

 df = pd.concat([df,df2], ignore_index=True,axis=1)
 print(list(df))
```

Output: `[0,1]`
Expected Output: `[foo,bar]` (order is not important)
Is there any way to concatenate two dataframes without losing the original column headers, if I can guarantee that the headers will be unique?
Iterating through the columns and then adding them to one of the DataFrames comes to mind, but is there a pandas function, or `concat` parameter that I am unaware of?

Thanks!

Comment: `Passing ignore_index=True will drop all name references.` do you need to pass ignore_index?

Comment: As @umutto said... leave `ignore_index=True` or don't pass it at all.

Comment: Alright that seems to work! If you would be kind enough to post that as an answer, I would be glad to accept it!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As stated in [merge, join, and concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-with-mixed-ndims) documentation, ignore index will remove all name references and use a range (0...n-1) instead. So it should give you the result you want once you remove `ignore_index` argument or set it to false (default).

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

This will join your df and df2 based on indexes (same indexed rows will be concatenated, if other dataframe has no member of that index it will be concatenated as nan).

If you have different indexing on your dataframes, and want to concatenate it this way. You can either create a temporary index and join on that, or set the new dataframe's columns after using concat(..., ignore_index=True).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the accepted answer answers the question, which is about column headers, not indexes.

I am facing the same problem, and my workaround is to add the column names after the concatenation:

```
df.columns = ["foo", "bar"]
```