# Want to compare 2 rows in dateframe but ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled (both index and columns) DataFrame objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I concat two dataframes that can contain duplicates. The len of the df does not change after drop_duplicates, altough i knew that atleast one duplicate is there

I tried re_index , ignore_index in concat but still no duplicates where removed, because i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528119/pandas-recalculate-index-after-a-concatenation) that can be a problem after concat.
The len of the first df is 303 and the next df is appended there so index 303 is the first index of of df2

so i tried to check if the rows can be compared

in this index 0 contains the same data as 303 , beside that text Nan and the other is empty, makes that a difference or is this interpreted as Nan as well?
The following code will show the table under the code:

```
print (dfAfterConcat.loc[[0,303]])


|index|sender     | subject |date                     |text |html                                             |
|-----|-----------|---------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------
| 0   |xxx@xxx.com|[Success]|2023-12-10 01:22:27+01:00| Nan |?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><html><...|          
| 303 |xxx@xxx.com|[Success]|2023-12-10 01:22:27+01:00|     |?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><html><...|
```

So I tried to check if the two rows are the same:

```
dfAferConcat.loc[[303]] == dfAfterConcat.loc[[0]]
```

Which then throws the following error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled (both index and columns) DataFrame objects

EDIT: In the Preview my table is shown correct any idea why it is not when i upload the questions ?

EDIT2: i made a workaround where i use the to_csv read_csv instead of the concat function

had something like this before :

```
dfAfterConcat = pd.concat([oldDf,newDf], ignore_index= True) # tried this with several parameters, with ignore_Index = false etc did not worked for me
```

and now i do it like this:

```
oldDf = pd.read_csv (pathOldDf, sep =";",index_col= 0) # with oldDf df.to_csv("./mails_"+str(date)+".csv",sep=";",index=True,index_label="index")
newDf.to_csv(pathOldDf, sep=";",mode ='a',header=False, index_label="index")
dfAfterConcat = pd.read_csv(pathOldDf, sep= ';',index_col=0)
dfAfterConcat.drop_duplicates(inplace= True)
dfAfterConcat.to_csv(pathOldDf,sep=";",index=True)
```

While this is not a really pythonic way, it is a atleast a working way for me. Esepcially the use the index_label ="index" helped a lot because it seems pandas is not sure how to treat unnamed columns when reading csv tables and do mulitindex etc to i guess that is where the error stems from so its better to explict tell the column for index. I also used re_index etc when using the concat function but then i had a correct index but the duplicate function did not work

Comment: @user19077881 yes i tried this for concat did not change anything sadly also tried sort_index and similiar things , pandas version:2.0.3

Comment: Try `dfAferConcat.loc[[303]].eq(dfAfterConcat.loc[[0]])`

Comment: that way it does not throw an error but the result confuses me because it returns false for every value :  ` Text   date   html  sender  subject
0    False  False  False   False    False
303  False  False  False   False    False`

Comment: `dfAferConcat.loc[[0]].eq(dfAfterConcat.loc[[0]])` This does function but interestingly it does not give True for every column but gives false for the column "Text" is because i wrote Text in capital letters ?

Comment: @yes my copy paste of the Series does not look good sadly i cant edit it anymore but for every column it says False , in the comparison of [0] == [0] its says true for every column besides "Text"

Comment: The `[0] == [0]`  issue is caused by the Nan. If you use `dfAferConcat['Text'] = dfAferConcat['Text'].fillna('')` then it should go away.

Comment: Yes that is true , so after That all coloumns are True, but sadly this does not work for the appended df at index 303

Comment: It would greatly help if you could produce a (small) reproducible  code example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i try, i but i deleted a lot of code must find the version where the error occured, i made a workaround where i instead of using concat writing to a CSV in mode "a" (append) and given index_label ="index" , this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the nan values with 0 first before the drop ducplicates

`dfAfterConcat['text'].fillna('', inplace=True)`

Comment: interestingly when i do fillna("") both a empty but when i do (fill("0") just the Nan value is = 0 , so maybe for pandas the row with text is =/ Nan i could try to check if the value of the column for 303 is NaN to check that

Comment: so i tried  `print(type(dfAfterConcat.loc[303]["Text"]))` resulting in `<class 'str'>` so it seems that pandas does not think it is Nan rather it is the following String ""

Comment: `print(type(dfAfterConcat.loc[0]["Text"])` results in `<class 'float'>` as exspected because Nan is stored as float, when i do the fillna it prints type `<class 'str'>` for [0] but then the error still occurs, should it not return false then, i find this a bit strange

Comment: Yes exactly in 303 it's an empty string means it has value ='' and not nan.
Could you try casting all the column to string ?