# Link dataframe columns on another dataframe, under condition

Tags: python, pandas

Following the questions:
[Python Pandas Only Compare Identically Labeled DataFrame Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557131/python-pandas-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects) & [How to create a new data frame based on conditions from another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455457/how-to-create-a-new-data-frame-based-on-conditions-from-another-data-frame).

I am trying to create a column in an already existing dataframe df1 with values conditioned on another already existing dataframe df2 with different index and columns.

In df2 ['Home'] cities have a ['Home_ranking']. I need to match the ['Home_ranking'] in df1 with those of df2, the condition being that ['Home'] cities should match.
For instance, city B is the first ['Home'] city in df1, I need to get it's ranking in df2, which is 2. So that the first ['Home_ranking'] in df1 is 2 and so forth.

df1 has 50 rows and more columns and df2 only has 20 rows and 4 columns.

```
>>> print(df1)
      Home     Away     Home_ranking    Away_ranking    [other columns..]
0   city B   city C                0               0
1   city D   city D                0               0
2   city B   city D                0               0
3   city A   city A                0               0

>>> print(df2)
      Home     Away     Home_ranking    Away_ranking
0   city A   city B               12               5
1   city D   city C                4               7
2   city F   city A                1               9
3   city B   city D                2               8
```

Expected result

```
>>> print(df1)
      Home     Away     Home_ranking    Away_ranking
0   city B   city C                2               7
1   city D   city D                4               8
2   city B   city D                2               8
3   city A   city A               12               9
```

I have tried many things suggested in the previous questions, but none of the seem to work for me. I have also tried:

```
for i in df1.Home :
    if df1.Home == df2.Home :
       df1['Home_ranking'][i] = df2.Home_ranking[i]
```

yields "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

```
df1['Home_ranking'][i] = df2.loc[(df2['Home'] == df1['Home'][i])].Home_ranking
```

yields "KeyError: 'city B'
I am lost, any help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`map()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the rankings:

- For `Home_rankings`, the `Home` column is the matching key, so set `df2`'s index to `Home` and map its `Home_ranking` to `df1['Home']`.
- For `Away_rankings`, the key is `Away`, so set `df2`'s index to `Away` and map its `Away_ranking` to `df1['Away']`.

```py
df1['Home_ranking'] = df1['Home'].map(
    df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Home']).set_index('Home')['Home_ranking'])

df1['Away_ranking'] = df1['Away'].map(
    df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Away']).set_index('Away')['Away_ranking'])

#      Home    Away  Home_ranking  Away_ranking
# 0  city B  city C             2             7
# 1  city D  city D             4             8
# 2  city B  city D             2             8
# 3  city A  city A            12             9
```

---

For this use case, mapping should be faster (and scale better) than merging:

```py
%%timeit
df1['Home'].map(df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Home']).set_index('Home')['Home_ranking'])
df1['Away'].map(df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Away']).set_index('Away')['Away_ranking'])

# 2.92 ms ± 72.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
(df1.drop(columns=['Home_ranking', 'Away_ranking'])
    .merge(df2[['Home', 'Home_ranking']], how='left', on='Home')
    .merge(df2[['Away', 'Away_ranking']], how='left', on='Away')

# 4.59 ms ± 30.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks @tdy, I feel this is going in the right direction, but it still yields: 'InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'. Which I think I can probably get around, but still costly in terms of lines of code. Does it mean df1['Home'] needs unique value? ..which is not the case..

Comment: @JoeBadAss ah ok, then the issue is actually dupes in `df2`. the updated answer (with `drop_duplicates`) should take care of that.

Comment: Yes it was, thanks @tdy! I was persuaded that there were no duplicates but there was..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loops. This is a couple of merge operations:

```py
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({
    "Home": list("BDBA"),
    "Away": list("CDDA"),
    "Home_Ranking": [0] * 4,
    "Away_Ranking": [0] * 4,
})


df2 = pandas.DataFrame({
    "Home": list("ADFB"),
    "Away": list("BCAD"),
    "Home_Ranking": [12, 4, 1 ,2],
    "Away_Ranking": [5, 7, 9, 8],
})


results = (
    df1.drop(columns=["Home_Ranking", "Away_Ranking"])
       .merge(df2[["Home", "Home_Ranking"]], how='left', on="Home")
       .merge(df2[["Away", "Away_Ranking"]], how='left', on="Away")
)
```

And that gets you:

```
Home Away  Home_Ranking  Away_Ranking
   B    C             2             7
   D    D             4             8
   B    D             2             8
   A    A            12             9
```

Comment: thanks @Paul H, it only works for one row, the row that matches both Home and Away columns in df1 & df2 though. the other rows that don't match gets nan's unfortunately

Comment: If the keys don't match, what are you expecting top happen @JoeBadAss?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Paul H. My question was poorly asked. I have rephrased slightly and I hope and it answers your question.

Comment: @JoeBadAss ahh I see. Still don't need any loops. check the update