# Confirming equality of two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

How to assert that the following two dataframes `df1` and `df2` are equal?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1.0, 2, 3])
```

The output of `df1.equals(df2)` is `False`.
As of now, I know two ways:

```
print (df1 == df2).all()[0]
```

or

```
df1 = df1.astype(float)
print df1.equals(df2)
```

It seems a little bit messy. Is there a better way to do this comparison?

Comment: NumPy for help : `np.allclose(df1,df2)`?

Comment: @Divakar `np.allclose(df1, df2)` works for this case. But what if you have some strings in your dataframes as well?

Comment: @Divakar, could you please add it as an answer - it could help others in future?

Comment: @MaxU Hmm I am not sure, was mostly a wild guess. Also, as OP pointed out for strings it might be producing unexpected output?

Comment: try this: `np.allclose(df1.select_dtypes(exclude=[object]), df2.select_dtypes(exclude=[object])) & df1.select_dtypes(include=[object]).equals(df2.select_dtypes(include=[object]))` - it's based on @Divakar's solution

Comment: What do you mean by strings? Strings like `1.0` so that you want `'1.0' == 1` to return True?

Comment: @ayhan, I guess OP means strings like `'a string'`...

Comment: @MaxU That looks like a reasonable solution! Seems to gracefully take care of strings. Consider posting that extended version as an answer.

Comment: @Divakar, the main idea belongs to you, i've just extended it a bit with a strings comparison, so please post it as an answer - it will definitely help people in future :)

Comment: @MaxU I think you made the big changes needed there. My pandas knowledge is very limited, so I won't be able to put in words there. So, please do the honors! You can just attribute to the comments if needed :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `assert_frame_equal` and not check the dtype of the columns.

```
# Pre v. 0.20.3
# from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_dtype=False)
```

Comment: With pandas 0.20.3 `assert_frame_equal` is in the `pandas.testing` package: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html

Comment: And important to notice, if there is no any output after the execution of assert_frame_equal function, then the two dataframes are equal.

Answer (score 7):

Using [elegant @Divakar's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212697/confirming-equality-of-two-pandas-dataframes?noredirect=1#comment63849479_38212697) - numpy's [allclose()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) will do the main trick for numbers:

```
In [128]: df1
Out[128]:
   0    s  n
0  1  aaa  1
1  2  aaa  2
2  3  aaa  3

In [129]: df2
Out[129]:
     0    s    n
0  1.0  aaa  1.0
1  2.0  aaa  2.0
2  3.0  aaa  3.0

In [130]: (np.allclose(df1.select_dtypes(exclude=[object]), df2.select_dtypes(exclude=[object]))
   .....:  &
   .....:  df1.select_dtypes(include=[object]).equals(df2.select_dtypes(include=[object]))
   .....: )
Out[130]: True
```

[select_dtypes()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) will help you to separate strings and all other numeric dtypes