# Compare values from two pandas data frames, order-independent

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unordered

I am new to data science. I want to check which elements from one data frame exist in another data frame, e.g.

```
df1 = [1,2,8,6]
df2 = [5,2,6,9]

# for 1 output should be False

# for 2 output should be True

# for 6 output should be True
```

etc.

Note: I have matrix not vector.

I have tried using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    priority_dataframe = pd.read_excel(prioritylist_file_path, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=None)

    priority_dict = {column: np.array(priority_dataframe[column].dropna(axis=0, how='all').str.lower()) for column in
                         priority_dataframe.columns}
    keys_found_per_sheet = []
    if file_path.lower().endswith(('.csv')):
        file_dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    else:
        file_dataframe = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet, index=None)

    file_cell_array = list()
    for column in file_dataframe.columns:
        for file_cell in np.array(file_dataframe[column].dropna(axis=0, how='all')):
            if isinstance(file_cell, str) == 'str':
                file_cell_array.append(file_cell)
            else:
                file_cell_array.append(str(file_cell))

    converted_file_cell_array = np.array(file_cell_array)

    for key, values in priority_dict.items():
        for priority_cell in values:
            if priority_cell in converted_file_cell_array[:]:
                keys_found_per_sheet.append(key)
                break
```

I am doing something wrong in `if priority_cell in converted_file_cell_array[:]` ?

Is there any other efficient way to do that?

Comment: Can you add some data samples and expected output? I think [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confirming equality of two pandas dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212697/confirming-equality-of-two-pandas-dataframes)

Comment: @JaredWilber ,not really because, i want to check existence of each element of one data frame into another data frame.

Comment: In other words, you want to check if two dataframes have exactly the same elements, but the positions do not matter, right?

Comment: My bad. I think you should further clarify the question, I'm still confused what you're asking.

Comment: @DyZ, sorry , I want to check which element from one data frame exist in another data frame.

Comment: Anywhere? At any position? Or at the same position?

Comment: @ Dyz, anywhere at any position, I have updated my question please check.

Comment: You can take the `.values` from each dataframe, convert them to a `set()`, and take the set difference (subtract the sets).

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - There are same types of values? Is possible use `df1.isin(df2.values.ravel())` ?

Comment: @DyZ, I thing this could be the ans can you post answer with example.

Comment: **You say "dataframe" but you show a 1D dataframe/Series, then you say "Note: I have matrix not vector". Which is it?** And `df1 = [1,2,8,6]` is a plain Python list, not any of those. Please give executable code (MCVE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the `.values` from each dataframe, convert them to a `set()`, and take the set intersection.

```
set1 = set(df1.values.reshape(-1).tolist())
set2 = set(dr2.values.reshape(-1).tolist())
different = set1 & set2
```

Comment: Got error `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'reshape'`.

Comment: Is `df1` indeed a DataFrame?

Comment: soryy it was my mistake.

Comment: I want to know what are the element from set1 exist in set2. Will set difference work, I don't think so.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - Or use function `set.intersection`, then second list is not necessary convert to set.

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten all values of `DataFrame`s by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and then use [`set.intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df1)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,13,4], 'Z':list('abfr')})
print (df2)
    A  Z
0   2  a
1   3  b
2  13  f
3   4  r

L = list(set(df1.values.ravel()).intersection(df2.values.ravel()))
print (L)
['f', 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: I have already check this, but I want True/False output for each element so that I can do other stuff on that .

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - What is expected output? `dictionary` of boolens is correct?

Comment: Want list of all existing element.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - then `list(set(a).intersection(b))` should working.