# Error"Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" and sort_index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean

I have two dataframes `df1` `df2`with the same numbers of rows and columns and variables, and I'm trying to compare the boolean variable `choice` in the two dataframes. Then use `if/else` to manipulate the data. But something seems wrong when I try to compare the boolean var.

Here are my dataframes sample and codes:

```
#df1
v_100     choice #boolean
7          True
0          True
7          False
2          True

#df2
v_100     choice #boolean
1          False
2          True
74         True
6          True

def lastTwoTrials_outcome():
     df1 = df.iloc[5::6, :] #df1 and df2 are extracted from the same dataframe first
     df2 = df.iloc[4::6, :]

     if df1['choice'] != df2['choice']:  # if "choice" is different in the two dataframes
         df1['v_100'] = (df1['choice'] + df2['choice']) * 0.5
```

Here's the error:

```
if df1['choice'] != df2['choice']:
File "path", line 818, in wrapper
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I found the same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error), and an answer suggests to `sort_index` first, but I don't really understand why though? Can anyone explain more in detail please (if that's the correct solution)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for same index values and then comapare - for create new column is better use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

Also instead `+` use `|`  because working with booleans.

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
df1['v_100'] = df1['choice'].mask(df1['choice'] != df2['choice'],
                                  (df1['choice'] + df2['choice']) * 0.5)


df1['v_100'] = np.where(df1['choice'] != df2['choice'],
                       (df1['choice'] | df2['choice']) * 0.5,
                        df1['choice'])
```

Samples:

```
print (df1)
   v_100  choice
5      7    True
6      0    True
7      7   False
8      2    True

print (df2)
   v_100  choice
4      1   False
5      2    True
6     74    True
7      6    True
```

---

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   v_100  choice
0      7    True
1      0    True
2      7   False
3      2    True

print (df2)
   v_100  choice
0      1   False
1      2    True
2     74    True
3      6    True

df1['v_100'] = df1['choice'].mask(df1['choice'] != df2['choice'],
                                  (df1['choice'] | df2['choice']) * 0.5)

print (df1)
   v_100  choice
0    0.5    True
1    1.0    True
2    0.5   False
3    1.0    True
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I have tried both of them, but still the exact error occurs.

Comment: What is `print (df1.index)` and `print (df2.index)` ?  What is `print (len(df1.index))` and `print (len(df2.index))` ?

Comment: `print (df1.index)` : RangeIndex(start=5, stop=2160, step=6)
`print (df2.index)` : RangeIndex(start=4, stop=2160, step=6)
`print (len(df1.index))` : 360
`print (len(df2.index))`: 360 . Thanks!

Comment: So problem is indexes are different - different `start=5` vs `start=4`. do you try reset_index?

Comment: Yes, the prints are after `reset_index`. So why are they still have different start then? I re-checked that they do have the same numbers of rows and columns.

Comment: oops, I see it. need `drop=True`

Comment: my bad, I did not reassign the var `df1` and `df2`...Sorry....It does work PERFECTLY. Thanks for your help!!! @jezrael

Comment: Do you assign output like `df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)` or only uses `df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Answer (score 9):

The error happens because you compare two pandas.Series objects with different indices. A simple solution would be to compare just the values in the series. Try it:

```
if df1['choice'].values != df2['choice'].values
```