# How to compare two data in python

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

can any tell me how to compare two data

I want to get a signal if open_15 if less than r1
when I tried this, I'm getting an error called "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

can anyone suggest a solution

---

````
import yfinance as yf

yf.pdr_override()
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("RELIANCE.NS", start="2020-04-24", end="2020-05-24", interval="15m")
data_15 = data
close_15 = data_15['Close']
open_15 = data_15['Open']

data2 = pdr.get_data_yahoo("RELIANCE.NS", start="2020-04-24", end="2020-05-24")
data_1 = data2
close_1 = data2['Close']
high_1 = data2['High']
low_1 = data2['Low']

pivot = (high_1+low_1+close_1)/3
r1 = (2*pivot)-low_1
r2 = pivot+(high_1-low_1) ```


___________________________________________________________
````

Comment: "when I tried this"... okay, please also show *the code where you tried it*

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773017/errorcan-only-compare-identically-labeled-series-objects-and-sort-index)