# Compare two columns from different dataframes

Tags: python, compare

I have 2 dataframes. sdf and df. In the dataframe df there are different columns with different information about measuring stations and in one column is the respective address. Also sdf has a column with addresses. I want to find out which address sdf and df are the same. However, I have the problem that the addresses are written differently. (Sometimes the street is written out, sometimes not). That's why I wanted to compare the first 5 digits of the street name. And if this matches in each case, it should create a new column with this match.
Problem:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labelled Series objects

i tried so many different things but i get always the same error or it doesnt work at all

```
df['Adresses_compared'] = (df['adress'].str[0:5]==sdf['adress_c'].str[0:5])
```

I Also tried it with mask

```
df['Adresses_compared']= sdf.mask(sdf['adress_c']== df1.loc[0:5, 'adress'])
```

In the end, I want to find a kind of intersection of the addresses that occur in both data frames.

Comment: Please give sample dataset, would be good if you will add desire output as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error"Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" and sort\_index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773017/errorcan-only-compare-identically-labeled-series-objects-and-sort-index)

Comment: Thank you but no, I think my problem was, that I wanted to compare over every column insted of going over ever row.

Answer (score -1):

Although, the question is not clear.

I am guessing the issue with your code is your try to compare whole column instead of  went through each rows of both df.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'adress': ['AAAA A']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'adress_c': ['AAAA BBB ASA', 'YF832', 'A']})


df1['Adresses_compared'] = df1['adress'].apply(lambda r : [l for l in list(df2['adress_c']) if r[:5]==l[:5]])
```

Output:

```
0    [AAAA BBB ASA]
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

**Note**: The new coumn will the have the value as a list then after you filter

Comment: Thank you that helped actually and now the Code is working. Yes I was also writing some loop so that the code is going over every row, but it didnt work. I am kind of new in python. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Dilo would you like to add your tried code and Error in your question ?