# issues with processing a Pandas Dataframe one row at a time

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to process a dataframe one row at a time using iloc.
I have a sorted frame read in from a Database:

```
branch  animal  owner
00177   cat     Dave
00177   lion    Peter
00177   dog     Dave
00200   dog     Mary
00200   dog     Fred
00300   horse   Doug
00400   cat     Dave
```

I want to process each group of branch, so I thought if I compared each grpnum with the next one. like this:

```
for R in 0 to 7
    while [df.iloc[[R],[0]] == df.iloc[[R+1],[0]]
        do something
        R = R + 1
```

Except I got this error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Can I not process a DataFrame this way? How would one process a DataFrame row by row? I'm not tied to using a dataframe object, it was just convenient.
This example shows Branch with 4 distinct values. There are actually over a thousand different values, and the same branch can contain up to thirty records and as few as one.

Comment: Not sure if understand, can you add expected output? Do you need compare values between `groups` by `branch` column?

Comment: if you want to compare to the next row, look into the `DataFrame.shift` function. perhaps even `groupby` is what you really want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this sort of comparison the index is also compared

```
>>> df.iloc[[1],[0]]
branch
1  00177
>>> df.iloc[[0],[0]]
branch
0  00177
```

which in this case are 1 and 0 respectively

You can look for more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error)

You can try a different approach to your problem like

```
for i in range(7):
    if df["branch"][i] == df["branch"][i+1]:
        do something
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: [@jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8087057/jack-daniels) do you mean to compare `df["branch"][i]` with `df["branch"][i+1]` ?

Comment: I'm guessing jack meant [i+1], seeing as how it works nicely :)

Comment: Yeah! Typing mistake i guess.