# Python - ValueError: ('Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects', 'occurred at index Alkaline_Phosphotase')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I have dataFrame named data2 which consist 583 observation and 11 variables. there are outliers available in data. I want to impute outliers of my 3 variables named a,b and c. All are of int64 type. using IQR and mean imputation technique.I created two variable from my data2 Q1 and Q3.

```
Q1 = data2[['a','b','c']].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = data2[['a','b','c']].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
print (IQR)
```

Then I've defined two more variables i.e. lower_limit and upper_limit.

```
lower_limit = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
upper_limit = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR
```

Then I find mean values of a, b, and c.

```
mean_value = data2[['a','b','c']].mean()
print(mean_value)
```

Then I've Created one Function.

```
def imputer(value):
if value < lower_limit or value > upper_limit:
    return mean_value
else:
    return value
```

Now when I want to put values into dataframe using impute function which I have created earlier.

```
results = data2[['a','b','c']].apply(imputer) #Error Line
```

It Shows me error saying ValueError : 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.

Anyones help is appreciated.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error

Comment: I tried sort index values but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it by changing `axis` attribute of `apply` method, I also checked `Series'` [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) method but of no help. After all this what I have come up is that don't use your imputer method

```
for col in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    data2[col] = data2.apply(lambda row: mean_value[col] if (row[col] < lower_limit[col] and row[col] > upper_limit[col]) else row[col], axis=1)
```

I know this might be non efficient, but if anyone has an efficient answer or the way you were doing, then that can be great.