# Why does my boolean conditional generate a 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to add a feature column to my dataframe and match it to my existing dataframe rows by month and year (which I've stored in integer columns).

I've tried using `.iloc[]` to specify the row to add the new feature variable `df['Price Level']` that is taken from `i_df['CPIAUCNS']`, but after reading a lot of Stack Overflow, it seems like `np.where` is a more appropriate function for a conditional statement.

```
bool_filter = ((df['Release Date Year'] == i_df['Release Date Year']) 
               & (df['Release Date Month'] == i_df['Release Date Month']))

df['Price Level'] = np.where(bool_filter, i_df['CPIAUCNS'])
```

I was hoping this would generate a new feature column in `df` with the value from `i_df` where Year and Month were equal, instead I receive:

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

This error is thrown in the `bool_filter` so the `np.where` does not get to execute.

Would someone be able to explain why this conditional statement generates this error and how I might be able to rephrase it?

EDIT:

Trying to use `.values()` in the boolean filter results in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-9b470b5aee2c> in <module>()
      5 # df[df['Release Date'].isna() == True]
      6 
----> 7 bool_filter = ((df['Release Date Year'].values() == i_df['Release Date Year'].values()) 
      8                & (df['Release Date Month'].values() == i_df['Release Date Month'].values()))
      9 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: Try `== i_df['Release Date Month'].values` if you're not worried about index alignment.

Comment: Tried values, no luck. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION #1**

You should use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df = df.merge(i_df, how='left', left_on=['Release Date Year', 'Release Date Month'],
right_on=['Release Date Year', 'Release Date Month'])
```

This will join you `i_df` df to your `df` dataframe. It will do a `left` join in this example, but feel free to change the join type.

You will end up with a new df with the column you desire.

---

**SOLUTION #2**

Another solution, would be to use your boolean filter to filter your `i_df` dataframe

```
bool_filter = ((df['Release Date Year'] == i_df['Release Date Year']) 
               & (df['Release Date Month'] == i_df['Release Date Month']))

df['Price Level'] = i_df[bool_filter == True].CPIAUCNS
```

Now, this will consider that indexes of both dataframe are aligned. Becarefully if you cannot guarantee that both indexes are aligned.

Comment: For solution 2, do you know why when I write the bool_filter as below:

`bool_filter = ((df['Release Date Year'] == i_df['Release Date Year']) 
               & (df['Release Date Month'] == i_df['Release Date Month']))`

 I get `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: You may want to compare your data type from your df and i_df using df.info() and i_df.info(). You may have data type miss match between your 2 data frame or some null values.

Comment: You may want to checkout this SO post for your question regarding the error. It may have to do with your index in both of your df. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error

Answer (score 0):

Based on Teddy's answer I finally succeeded with the following merge statement:

```
df = df.merge(i_df[['Release Date Year', 'Release Date Month','CPIAUCNS']], 
              how='left', on=['Release Date Year', 'Release Date Month'])
```

I ended up with `CPIAUCNS` in my dataframe, which was my goal. Thanks Teddy!

However, I still don't understand the problem with my initial bool_filter.