# Getting 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects' after using chunksize in read_sql_query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with file-file and file-sql comparisons. Since the size of my data is large so I am forced to use chunksize of pandas dataframe.
For testing purpose I have used the same data in both file-file as well as file-sql. When I do the file-file comparison all works out good. However when I use chunksize for read_sql_query, things works out fine for the first chunk, but I get following message when second chunk is being processed:

*ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects*

Error happens specifically at this code

`ne_stacked = (src_df != tgt_df).stack()`

I tried to get any difference in the columns but all look good:

`print(src_df.columns)`

*Index(['firstname', 'lastname', 'account_num', 'salary', 'rental_income',
'int_yield', 'dividend', 'royalty', 'mortgage', 'car_loan', 'rent',
'other_expense', 'created_at', 'updated_at'],
dtype='object')*

`print(tgt_df.columns)`

*Index(['firstname', 'lastname', 'account_num', 'salary', 'rental_income',
'int_yield', 'dividend', 'royalty', 'mortgage', 'car_loan', 'rent',
'other_expense', 'created_at', 'updated_at'],
dtype='object')*

Can you please help in figuring out what is going on.

Comment: That's perhaps a problem with the index. Does this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18548888/14394522

Comment: No, it did not help. Added `tgt_df.sort_index(inplace=True)` but still getting same issue.

Comment: What about this  ```(src_df.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)) != (tgt_df.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1))``` ? And you could try ```.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)``` on each dataframe too.