# Error when using variables to filter dataframe with multiple conditions (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a temporary dataframe that is created by filtering an existing dataframe (`stock_data`) based on two criteria;

1. The `stock_data` ticker column is matching the `tick_id` variable
2. The `stock_data` date column is within a range from `start` to `end` (the variables are created using `pd.to_datetime`)

I've attempted this using two different solutions

First:

```
temp = stock_data[(stock_data.ticker == tick_id) & (stock_data["date"].isin(pd.date_range(start, end)))]
```

Second:

```
mask = (stock_data.ticker == tick_id) & ((stock_data.date > start) & (stock_data.date <= end))

temp = stock_data.loc[mask]
```

Both solutions result in the same error:

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error

Comment: Seems like your tick_id is an issue. Are you sure you've defined it correct?

Comment: @GlebV It looks like my tick_id was inaccurate upon creation, I initially made my tick_id as a way to look up an individual transactions ticker in a for loop, but the indexing on my table was incorrect. I used .reset_index() before creating my tick_id and it fixed the issue, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error's telling you your `tick_id` Series has different labels to `stock_data['ticker']`. I'm guessing one is a ticker name like 'AAPL', the other is a numerical ticker-id? (or even worse, just auto-indexed 0,1,2... from the output of some previous operation)

**Solution: make ticker or tick_id the index to both series/dataframes.** Do this everywhere, if you can. No numerical indices. Then joins, aggregations etc. are trivially easy.

(PS this is better for mose use-cases, also makes exporting CSV or pickle more intuitive.)

Anyway, this looks like a bad attempt to do a join operation.

Comment: It looks like my tick_id was inaccurate upon creation, I initially made my tick_id as a way to look up an individual transactions ticker in a for loop, but the indexing on my table was incorrect. I used .reset_index() before creating my tick_id and it fixed the issue, thanks for the help