# How do I compare two data frames to show the difference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I am trying to compare two excel file that are different size, one has 5701 row and the other has 5904 row. The columns are Price and Project Description. I am trying to compare by text to see what the project difference are.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Text/Downloads/D1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Text/Downloads/D2.csv')


df['text_match'] = np.where(df['Project ID'] == df2['Project ID'], 'True', 'False')
print(df.loc[(df['text_match'] == 'False')])
```

I get the following error when I try to run the code:

```
raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: What are the headers of the two files?

Answer (score 0):

To compare 2 dfs - the numbers of records must be the same:

You can use:

```
df1.equals(df2)
```

then get - false, there isn't option to compare.

There is option to use:

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True) == df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

There is another option - cut the second df to (5701 rows)

```
# Number of rows to drop
n = 203
 
# Removing last n rows
df2 = df2.iloc[:-n]
```

Comment: You don't have to have the same number of records in 2 dataframes to compare them. The two have to have a column that would have the same value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error

Comment: The OP states that the number of records are NOT the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas [`.compare()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) function, as follows:

```
df.compare(df2)
```

Sample output is as follows:

```
  col1       col3
  self other self other
0    a     c  NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN  3.0   4.0
```

It highlight the differences with `self` for `df` and `other` for `df2`

You can just compare part of the columns by e.g.

```
df[['Project ID', 'Price']].compare(df2[['Project ID', 'Price']])
```

Or, if you just want to compare only the `Project ID` column:

```
df['Project ID'].compare(df2['Project ID'])
```

---

Another method is to try filtering for unmatched `Project ID`, using `.isin()`, as follows:

```
df.loc[~df['Project ID'].isin(df2['Project ID'])]
```

and:

```
df2.loc[~df2['Project ID'].isin(df['Project ID'])]
```

Comment: I tried the df1.compare(df2), it receive the following error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: @MDL7833  The 2 dataframes are of different column labels ?   You can rename one of them first

Comment: @MDL7833  You can also limit the number of columns to compare.  See my edit above.

Comment: @MDL7833  See also alternative approach to filter unmatched `Project ID` by `.isin()`.