# Looping through dataframe list with IF Statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just running a simple for-loop on a list of dataframes, however trying to add an IF clause... and it keeps erroring out.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in df_list:
   if df in [df1, df2]:
      x = 1
   else:
      x = 2
.
.
.
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Above is a simplified version of what I'm attempting. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working and a fix?

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: just updated it!

Comment: the error message is self-explanatory.  Maybe try it with equality?

Comment: I smell an XY problem here.  `if` statements in `for` loops are one thing, but your problem seems to come in when trying to evaluate if one dataframe is one of the dataframes in a list.  Do you want to know if it is the same object?  Or just has the same index, column, and values?  Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: I wanted to check whether they were the same object

Comment: @chicagobeast12 Then you should take my answer. `.equals()` adds burdens to comparing the values, but what you just need is to compare the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do NOT use `.equals()` here!**

It's unnecessary and slowing down you program, use `id()` instead:

```py
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in df_list:
   if id(df) in [id(df1), id(df2)]: 
      x = 1
   else:
      x = 2
```

Because here you just need to compare the identities, rather than the values.

Comment: Depending upon the use case `id` can be nice, but it could also be unwanted. For instance if `df3` was created with `df3=df1`, then they share the same `id`, yet for _some reason_ perhaps they should be handled differently. Guess that could be avoided with `df3=df1.copy()` so it's truly a different object, not just a reference

Comment: If `df3=df1` is in the case, then @ALollz 's answer will be your choice. Neither `id()` nor `.equals()` can distinguish them. But `id()` is able to tell `df3` from `df1` if `df3` is a copy of `df1`, while `.equals()` is not.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `DataFrame.equals` with `any` instead:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in df_list:
    if any(df.equals(y) for y in [df1, df2]):
        x = 1
    else:
        x = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a better container and reference them by labels.

Equality checks for large DataFrames with object types can become slow, >> seconds, but it will take ~ns to check if the label is in a list.

```
dfs = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3}
for label, df in dfs.items():
    if label in ['df1', 'df2']:
        x = 1
    else:
        x = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use df.equals()

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in df_list:
   if df.equals(df1) or df.equals(df2):
      # blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link might help:
[Pandas "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error)

According to this, the data frames being compared with `==` should have the same columns and index otherwise it gives the error.

Alternatively, you can compare the data frames using `dataframe.equals` method. Please refer to the documentation below: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html