# Error while comparing two pandas dataframce slice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have below two data frame slices, here t1 and t2 are current and previous dates,

```
> sales.source[t1]
 date
20220405      ALX
20220405     BVAL
20220405      EJV
20220405    IBOXX
20220405      ICE
20220405      ICE
20220405      IHS
20220405      IHS
20220405      LEH
20220405      LEH
20220405      J4D
20220405      JPH
20220405      MNB
20220405      PRS
20220405      LEH
20220405      FMG
20220405      FMG
20220405      FMG
20220405      FMG
20220405      FMG
Name: source, dtype: object

> sales.source[t2]
 date
20220404      ALX
20220404     BVAL
20220404      EJV
20220404    IBOXX
20220404      ICE
20220404      ICE
20220404      IHS
20220404      IHS
20220404      LEH
20220404      LEH
20220404      J4D
20220404      JPH
20220404      MNB
20220404      PRS
20220404      LEH
20220404      FMG
20220404      FMG
20220404      FMG
20220404      FMG
20220404      FMG
Name: source, dtype: object
```

When I try to compare them using `sales.source[t1] != sales.source[t2]` I get an error as below
Please suggest

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/sales/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib-stats/utils/failsafe.py", line 10, in wrapper
    x = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/sales/Sales.py", line 200, in run_checks
    sales_source_bool = sales.source[t1] != sales.source[t2]
  File "/projects/sales/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 65, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/projects/sales/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 365, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: Could you show sales data sample? Date is acting as Index. apply `reset_index(drop=True)` on both the slices It should work!.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error)