# Does pandas really perform index alignment?

Tags: pandas

In a long code, I found myself at a point where I had to compare two series. I can't share the full code but I made example :

```
series1 = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], index=[2, 1, 3])
series2 = pd.Series(['b', 'a', 'c'], index=[3, 2, 1])

print(series1)
2    a
1    b
3    c
dtype: object

print(series2)
3    b
2    a
1    c
dtype: object
```

For the comparison it's a simple `series1 == series2` but surprisingly I got an error :

> **ValueError**: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

To solve the problem I searched in stackoveflow and people say it's because of the different indexes which appear to be true because the code below solved my issue :
[Pandas "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error)

```
series1.sort_index() == series2.sort_index()

1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

My question is : do pandas really do index alignment ? Or is it just a myth ? Because I feel like sometimes it does and sometimes not.

Do you guys have an explanation to my error and an answer to my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer the use of [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) that is more powerful than `==` (likewise [`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html)/[`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html)/[`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html)/[`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) in place of `<=`/`<`/`>=`/`>`):

```
series1.eq(series2)
```

Output:

```
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Alternative with a manual reindexing:

```
series1 == series2.reindex_like(series1)

2     True
1    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Heh... I was just getting ready to post the `reindex_like` method myself. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston i still prefer the `eq` method that also has many advantages like being chainable, avoiding operator precedence issues…

Comment: Agreed.  That is what `eq` and all the other pandas methods are for; handling those special situations.