# DataFrame.to_dict() is not always invertible

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

My main point is that:

```
assert_frame_equal(DataFrame.from_dict(df.to_dict()), df)
```

fails in some cases. I would love to provide with a reproducible example but (i) the data would be too big to post, and (ii) for this I would need to provide with a DataFrame serialized (which is precisely where this fails...)

Is this a known issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason this can fail is that `df.to_dict()` creates a Python dictionary. The keys of dictionaries are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.

The DataFrame's column names are mapped to the dictionary keys and, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224172/equality-in-pandas-dataframes-column-order-matters), order of columns matters when testing DataFrame equality.

This fact is easy to check:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> pd.util.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict()))
# AssertionError
```

There are a number of [keyword arguments](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/util/testing.py#l689) you could pass in to the test to specify the criteria you want to check or ignore, including `check_names=False` (which is `True` by default).